# PLC - get absolute value of number when the CPU has no "ABS" instruction

Tags: cpu, math, plc

I am working with a "CLICK" PLC from automationdirect.  I am trying to set up a deadband for a specific process value X.  When X changes by more than a specified amount, something should happen.

The simple way to do this is to simply subtract the previous value of X from the current value.  Then if the absolute value of this result is greater than the allowable deadband, "do something".

However, the "CLICK" PLC doesn't have an ABS operator, that I can find.  The only way I can think of to simulate this is by doing SQRT(value ^ 2), which will always yield a positive number.  But this seems like huge overkill plus wasted CPU cycles, and the likelihood of overflow when larger numbers are in play.

I suppose I could AND the result with 0x7fff but that forces me to work with 16-bit numbers (the PLC doesn't allow AND operations on 32-bit INTs).

"CLICK" instruction set: https://cdn.automationdirect.com/static/specs/clickinstr.pdf

I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: Can't you just check if it is negative and multiply by `-1` or subtract from zero ? Really, not a big deal..

Comment: @EugeneSh. or first check if `a>b then diff= a-b else diff= b-a`

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am not even sure this subtraction is necessary. He could get away with comparisons only... Well, we don't have enough info.

Comment: Yes I realize that would work but it makes the ladder more complicated... was looking for a simple solution and was surprised at the lack of this basic operation.

Comment: Does it have a "SIGN" operator? If so, multiply A * Sign(A).

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to avoid sign comparison and multiplication by -1, then you can use the following procedure adapted from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org. Initially a 31-bit arithmetic right shift is performed (I am assuming here, 32-bit signed integers) to retrieve the sign bit - with extension. The central idea is to undo the complement of 2 if the number is negative (subtract 1 and invert with an or-exclusive, in that order). If the number is positive, a sum and an or-exclusive are performed with the value zero - with no effect at all. The code is in C, but can be adapted to your needs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BAND    15

int main() {
  int n = -20, mask;

  mask = n >> 0x1F;
  if (((n + mask) ^ mask) > BAND)
      printf("OUT OF BAND");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are missing an AND bitwise instruction, you can still perform the operation on a range of bits  repeating the following rung for all bits,

```
|  A_bit_0  B_bit_0        R_bit_0  |
|---[ ]------[ ]--------------( ) --|
|                                   |
```

And for bitwise OR,

```
|  A_bit_0                 R_bit_0  |
|--+-[ ]--+-------------------( ) --|
|  |      |                         |
|  | B_0  |                         |
|  +-[ ]--+                         |
```

Using this method for OR and XOR, even shift, you can transform the C code to PLC ladder logic.